# How to match two Lists in some condition in C#

Tags: c#, list, match

I've 3 Lists like this:

```
listA = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}

listB = {4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6}

listC = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
```

I want to match listA and listB elements. So, if listA elements match the listB's same element, I want to add these to another List listQ. For example;

```
listQ = {{10, 40}, {20, 50}, {30, 60}}
```

[image]

- listA's values 1 & 2 match listB's value 4. So I take that listC's same index.

How can I handle it?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
Because of a lot of repercussions, I attached new sample by image. I hope this will be helpful:

[image]

Comment: Matching is random or there is some rule?

Comment: I don't understand how matching listA and listB would render listQ.

Comment: I don't understand the task. `listA's` 1 is 1, `listA's` 2 is also 1, how does this match `list's` 4, which is 50?

Comment: You probably can with a LINQ query, but your definition of matching has no relation to the results

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy listA's 1 and 2 match listB's 4. Their indexes 0 and 3. So listC's 0 and 3. indexes have 10 and 40. These should be listQ's first elements.

Comment: Before I downvote as well, *WHY* does 1 or 2 match 4? Who defines this rule? Why not 5, 6 or 456? Why is the "index of 1" 0 and not 1 or 2 (these are both 1?)

Comment: May I suggest you delete this question, check your values then post a new question with a proper description of the matching algorithm? Constantly checking the edits is tiresome. And I still haven't downvoted yet

Comment: If you'd add the code demonstrating your current attempt (even if producing incorrect results) it could be less ambiguous, than natural language description.

Comment: @team16sah what if you have listB `{ 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5 }`? What output is expected? Also I suggest you to describe business rules you are trying to implement. What is stored in listA? What if it will have values `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}`? What is in listB? Why they should match?

Comment: It looks to me like you're just grouping values from listC that correspond to matching values in listB: listB[0] and listB[3] are both 4, so we get {listC[0], listC[3]} = {10, 40}. listA doesn't seem to have any involvement here.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy http://i.hizliresim.com/xB9OnG.png

Comment: So indeed ListA is not used at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't understand role of `listA`, but here is a query which returns your expected data:

```
var listQ = listB.Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
                 .GroupBy(bx => bx.b)
                 .Select(g => g.Join(listC.Select((c, i) => new { c, i }),
                                     bx => bx.i,
                                     cx => cx.i,
                                     (bx, cx) => cx.c).ToList()).ToList();
```

It groups `listB` items by their value (and preserves indexes of these values). That gives you three groups for your first sample:

```
Key | Items in group (first property is item value, second is item index)
 4  |  {4,0}, {4,3}
 5  |  {5,1}, {5,4}
 6  |  {6,2}, {6,5}
```

Then I join these groups by indexes with values in `listC`. I.e. for each group I select items from `listC` which have same indexes that `listB` items in group.

```
{4,0} -> {10,0}, {4,3} -> {40,3}
{5,1} -> {20,1}, {5,4} -> {50,4}
{6,2} -> {30,2}, {6,5} -> {60,5}
```

And last step - I project joined items and select only item values:

```
[
  [ 10, 40 ]
  [ 20, 50 ]
  [ 30, 60 ]
]
```

---

With your second example

```
var listA = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
var listB = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
var listC = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 };
```

Output will be

```
[
  [ 10, 40, 50 ],
  [ 20, 60, 70 ],
  [ 30 ]
]
```

Comment: +1 for quite good attempt at mind-reading ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and attention. But I take an error with this code block. The error is : http://i.hizliresim.com/ekY0B7.png

Comment: @team16sah I don't see any errors there - you have three items in `listQ`, btw that list have type `List<IEnumerable<int>>`, and it's items will be iterators

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Sorry my bad English. I don't want to say "Error". Linq is far away to me for now. I solved like this: 

List<List<int>> asList = new List<List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < listQ.Count; i++)
    asList.Add(listQ[i].ToList());

Is this well method for this?

Comment: @team16sah if you want `List<List<int>>` then simply add `ToList()` call after join: `.Select(g => g.Join(...).ToList()).ToList()`

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. @SergeyBerezovskiy. How can I take also their indexes with similar way? I'm new in Linq.

Comment: @team16sah change join result selection to `(bx, cx) => cx`. That will give you list of anonymous types, which contain both value from listC and it's index